# Docker Image running correctly on one machine but failing on another

Tags: docker, istio

When Trying to install Istio 1.2.3 on my cluster using Helm, I encountered an issue with the istio/kubectl image being used in the istio-init jobs with the following error:

```
container_linux.go:295: starting container process caused "exec: \"kubectl\": executable file not found in $PATH"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:295: starting container process caused "exec: \"kubectl\": executable file not found in $PATH".
```

Running the kubectl command in my local docker also gives the same error, however on another machine it works correctly

```
docker run <istio/kubectl-imageid> kubectl
```

What could cause this issue? And what would I need to change to overcome it?

It is definitely the same docker image and from my understanding a docker image should work identically in different environments assuming the same cpu architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when I copied the image across machines, I did a

```
docker import istio-kubectl.1.2.3.tar
```

instead of a

```
docker load istio-kubectl.1.2.3.tar
```

The difference according to the documentation is:

docker load: Load an image from a tar archive or STDIN
docker import: Import the contents from a tarball to create a filesystem image

Loading the image instead of importing corrected the observed issue.